# SQL Server how to get around the transaction log filling up when updating a column to an int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transaction-log

I have a SQL Server 2005 table called `BRITTNEY_SPEARS_MARRIAGES` and it has the following columns:

```
MarrigeId tinyint, 
HusbandName varchar(500),
MarrigeLength int
```

Now I have another table `BRITTNEY_SPEARS_MARRIAGE_STORIES`

```
StoryId int, 
MarriageId tinyint, 
StoryText nvarchar(max)
```

The problem is we want to update `MarrigeId` column to an `int` from a `tinyint`. We just feel that Brittney is going to have lots of marriages before everything is said and done.

Now the `BRITTNEY_SPEARS_MARRIAGE_STORIES` table has 18 million rows in it (hey the girl has some issues) so when we go to do the update the transaction log fills up and our SQL Server box dies.

How can we get around this?

Is there anyway to say "Hey SQL Server I'm going to update this column and make it bigger. Trust me on this SQL Server. Please don't fill up the transaction log while you attempt to validate everything?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to tell SQL Server not to use the transaction log.

What you *can* do is set the recovery model of the database to SIMPLE, which will overwrite old log entries as space is needed.  You should not do this on your production server, however, because you won't be able to do certain types of restores, such as point-in-time restores.

Alternatively, you can set your transaction log file to be larger -- as an unscientific rule of thumb I'd make sure that either A) your transaction log has *at least* about 1.5x more free space than the size of your table or B) that your transaction log can auto-grow to a drive which has *at least* about this amount of disk space free.

You can free transaction log space by backing up the log.  If you don't care about the log contents, throw the file away.   A shortcut for this is `BACKUP LOG <Your Database Name> TO DISK = 'NUL:'`.  Again, don't do this on a production server **unless you are absolutely sure you understand the implications.**

Another thing to be careful of (though it's not entirely germane to your question) is to make sure the table you're expanding has a clustered index defined on it.  If it does not, the table could incur a very large amount of heap fragmentation, and potentially become needlessly large on a change like this.

Answer (score 5):

- Drop any foreign keys
- Create new tables with `int` instead of `tinyint`
- Move the rows over per batch of 1000 (insert them in the new table, delete them from the old one)
- Drop the old tables
- Rename the new tables to the old names using [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx)
- Recreate the foreign keys

p.S. If your transaction log is large... check your recovery model.  If your recovery model is not `simple`, how long was it since you last backed up the log?

Comment: You mean since you backed up the log, backing up the database won't make the log smaller.

Comment: @HLGEM: You're right, I just read an article from Paul Randal on that topic.  Kind of unexpected though, if you'd only do full backups your log would keep growing.

Comment: wouldn't a more minimal approach be add a new int column, update with old column (batched if needed), drop column, rename column?